# subprocess + multiprocessing - multiple commands in sequence

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a set of command line tools that I'd like to run in parallel on a series of files.  I've written a python function to wrap them that looks something like this:

```
def process_file(fn):
    print os.getpid()
    cmd1 = "echo "+fn
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd1))

    # after cmd1 finishes
    other_python_function_to_do_something_to_file(fn)

    cmd2 = "echo "+fn
    p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd2))
    print "finish"

if __name__=="__main__":
    import multiprocessing
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for fn in files:
        RETURN = p.apply_async(process_file,args=(fn,),kwds={some_kwds})
```

While this works, it does not seem to be running multiple processes; it seems like it's just running in serial (I've tried using `Pool(5)` with the same result).  What am I missing?  Are the calls to `Popen` "blocking"?

EDIT: Clarified a little.  I need cmd1, then some python command, then cmd2, to execute in sequence on each file.

EDIT2:  The output from the above has the pattern:

```
pid
finish
pid
finish
pid
finish
```

whereas a similar call, using `map` in place of `apply` (but without any provision for passing `kwds`) looks more like

```
pid
pid
pid
finish
finish
finish
```

However, the map call sometimes (always?) hangs after apparently succeeding

Comment: Before answering this… why do you need `multiprocessing` at all? You can create a whole bunch of `Popen` instances in one process, and they'll be just as parallel as if you created them in multiple processes.

Comment: Well, that's part of my question (so thanks for helping me clarify)... my shell commands need to be run in series (i.e., cmd1, cmd2, cmd3).  I want each *series* to be performed on each file.

Comment: @abarnert is right. Just don't call `communicate` or `wait` on the processes

Comment: The shell commands won't be run in series, because you're just creating a `Popen` and leaving it to run in the background. As @JBernardo says, you have to wait on it—but don't use `communicate` when you can use the much simpler `check_call`.

Comment: Well, `map` is waiting for all of the children to finish before it returns, while `apply_async` returns immediately. If you don't want to block until all jobs are done, use `map_async` or `imap_unordered`. But I think in this case, you do want to block, right? Anyway, in your use case, I'm not sure the benefit of simplifying dispatch outweighs the complexity of wrapping functions calls up, so I don't know how far you need to pursue this part.

Comment: As for `map` hanging… are you sure that all of the jobs have finished? This is actually a pain to debug… but if you switch to `imap_unordered` you can get more feedback on what's going on. (The code for `multiprocessing.Pool` is really pretty simple—take a look at it.)

Comment: No, that's the problem - one subprocess is not finishing.  If I run the command "by hand" on the command line, it returns with nonzero exit status (it fails).  In subprocess, though, it just hangs - what can I do about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the calls to `Popen` "blocking"?

No. Just creating a `subprocess.Popen` returns immediately, giving you an object that you could wait on or otherwise use. If you want to block, that's simple:

```
subprocess.check_call(shlex.split(cmd1))
```

Meanwhile, I'm not sure why you're putting your args together into a string and then trying to `shlex` them back to a list. Why not just write the list?

```
cmd1 = ["echo", fn]
subprocess.check_call(cmd1)
```

> While this works, it does not seem to be running multiple processes; it seems like it's just running in serial

What makes you think this? Given that each process just kicks off two processes into the background as fast as possible, it's going to be pretty hard to tell whether they're running in parallel.

If you want to verify that you're getting work from multiple processing, you may want to add some prints or logging (and throw something like `os.getpid()` into the messages).

Meanwhile, it looks like you're trying to exactly duplicate the effects of `multiprocessing.Pool.map_async` out of a loop around `multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async`, except that instead of accumulating the results you're stashing each one in a variable called `RESULT` and then throwing it away before you can use it. Why not just use `map_async`?

Finally, you asked whether `multiprocessing` is the right tool for the job. Well, you clearly need something asynchronous: `check_call(args(file1))` has to block `other_python_function_to_do_something_to_file(file1)`, but at the same time not block `check_call(args(file2))`.

I would probably have used `threading`, but really, it doesn't make much difference. Even if you're on a platform where process startup is expensive, you're already paying that cost because the whole point is running N * M bunch of child processes, so another pool of 8 isn't going to hurt anything. And there's little risk of either accidentally creating races by sharing data between threads, or accidentally creating code that looks like it shares data between processes that doesn't, since there's nothing to share. So, whichever one you like more, go for it.

The other alternative would be to write an event loop. Which I might actually start doing myself for this problem, but I'd regret it, and you shouldn't do it…

Comment: OK, so if I want my shell commands to run in series, `check_call` is the way to go.  Does it then make sense to use `multiprocessing`?    (re:shlex - my actual commands are more complex than the simple example I included)

Comment: Now that I understand the problem, yes, `multiprocessing` is at least an option. You want to block on the first process for the first file before calling the second process for the first file… but not before calling the first process on the second file. I'd probably do it with either `threading` (or I might even write a `select` loop, and then beat my head against the wall when it came time to port to Windows…), but `multiprocessing` will work fine.

Comment: Great, thanks, this makes a lot of sense.  I used `apply` instead of `map` because I need to pass keyword arguments to the function.  Would it make more sense to wrap or decorate my function with a kwarg parser and then use `map_async`?

Comment: re: Why do I think they're not separate processes?  Because I get my output results in serial order.  i.e., my inputs are f1,f2,f3,f4,...,f30, I run with 4 processes, and every one outputs in order sequentially with the same time separation between each; if they were running in parallel the order would be random.  BUT, they do have different pid's.  Hmm.

Comment: Another way to verify multiple processes is to throw in random delays at various places (both in the tasks, and between the applies) to increase the variation. Often this can be enough to drive it from "every 1000 times I get one f out of order" to "on average I get 17 fs out of order"…

Comment: If I use `Pool().map`, 10 processes start & finish nearly simultaneously - there's a clear difference.   See EDIT 2.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer your other question, about the kwargs. The `map` method only works for functions of one argument, which means yes, you do need to wrap things up in, e.g., a tuple of a list and a dict, and pass a wrapper equivalent to `lambda arg: realFunc(*arg[0], **arg[1])` in place of `realFunc`. Which may be adding more work than you're saving in the dispatch, I said in the comments to the question.