# How do I embed my shell scanning-script into a Python script?

Tags: python, shell, scanning

Iv'e been using the following shell command to read the image off a scanner named scanner_name and save it in a file named file_name

```
scanimage -d <scanner_name> --resolution=300 --format=tiff --mode=Color 2>&1 > <file_name>
```

This has worked fine for my purposes.
I'm now trying to embed this in a python script. What I need is to save the scanned image, as before, into a file and also capture any std output (say error messages) to a string

I've tried

```
    scan_result = os.system('scanimage -d {} --resolution=300 --format=tiff --mode=Color 2>&1 > {} '.format(scanner, file_name))
```

But when I run this in a loop (with different scanners), there is an unreasonably long lag between scans and the images aren't saved until the next scan starts (the file is created as an empty file and is not filled until the next scanning command). All this with scan_result=0, i.e. indicating no error

The subprocess method run() has been suggested to me, and I have tried

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as scanfile:

    input_params = '-d {} --resolution=300 --format=tiff --mode=Color 2>&1 > {} '.format(scanner, file_name)
    scan_result = subprocess.run(["scanimage", input_params], stdout=scanfile, shell=True)
```

but this saved the image in some kind of an unreadable file format

Any ideas as to what may be going wrong? Or what else I can try that will allow me to both save the file and check the success status?

Comment: You can't use `subprocess.run([... list ...], shell=True)`, it's either pass a single sting with `shell=True` or pass a list of tokens with no shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.run()` is definitely preferred over `os.system()` but neither of them as such provides support for running multiple jobs in parallel.  You will need to use something like Python's [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) library to run several tasks in parallel (or painfully reimplement it yourself on top of the basic `subprocess.Popen()` API).

You also have a basic misunderstanding about how to run `subprocess.run()`.  You can pass in either a string and `shell=True` or a list of tokens and `shell=False` (or no `shell` keyword at all; `False` is the default).

```
with_shell = subprocess.run(
    "scanimage -d {} --resolution=300 --format=tiff --mode=Color 2>&1 > {} ".format(
        scanner, file_name), shell=True)

with open(file_name) as write_handle:
    no_shell = subprocess.run([
        "scanimage", "-d", scanner, "--resolution=300", "--format=tiff",
            "--mode=Color"],  stdout=write_handle)
```

You'll notice that the latter does not support redirection (because that's a shell feature) but this is reasonably easy to implement in Python. (I took out the redirection of standard error -- you really want error messages to remain on stderr!)

If you have a larger working Python program this should not be awfully hard to integrate with a `multiprocessing.Pool()`. If this is a small isolated program, I would suggest you peel off the Python layer entirely and go with something like `xargs` or GNU `parallel` to run a capped number of parallel subprocesses.

Comment: For more details perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538

Comment: I am skeptical of threading but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774781/python-multiple-subprocess-with-a-pool-queue-recover-output-as-soon-as-one-finis has some hints. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279813/subprocess-multiprocessing-multiple-commands-in-sequence is older (so maybe take it with a grain of salt) 
but closer to what I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is you're opening the output file, and then running the `subprocess.run()` within it. This isn't necessary. The end result is, you're opening the file via Python, then having the command open the file *again* via the OS, and then closing the file via Python.

*JUST* run the subprocess, and let the `scanimage 2>&1> filename` command create the file (just as it would if you ran the `scanimage` at the command line directly.)

I think `subprocess.check_output()` is now the preferred method of capturing the output.

I.e.

```
from subprocess import check_output
# Command must be a list, with all parameters as separate list items
command = ['scanimage', 
           '-d{}'.format(scanner), 
           '--resolution=300', 
           '--format=tiff', 
           '--mode=Color', 
           '2>&1>{}'.format(file_name)]

scan_result = check_output(command)
print(scan_result)
```

However, (with both `run` and `check_output`) that `shell=True` is a big security risk ... especially if the `input_params` come into the Python script externally. People can pass in unwanted commands, and have them run in the shell with the permissions of the script.

Sometimes, the `shell=True` is necessary for the OS command to run properly, in which case the best recommendation is to use an actual Python module to interface with the scanner - versus having Python pass an OS command to the OS.

Comment: You can't use shell features like redirection if you pass a list of tokens and `shell=False`.